# PHP weird Seg-faults on mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli, segmentation-fault

When migrating a PHP script from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3, I've stumbled to the following problem:
The general purpose of the script is data mining.
I have a procedure inside that adds data to the MySQL server.
Since it is really repetitive, I've rewritten it (a while ago) to use MySQLi, in particular prepared statements, since there are a total of 3 possible queries to perform.
Anyway, now, on the PHP 5.3 server, the script is crashing on the following line:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($prepCheck, $id1);
```

Where `$prepCheck` is created with `$prepCheck = mysqli_prepare($con, $checkQuery) or die("Error");`. The query runs fine on the MySQL server ($checkQuery, that is) and the PHP code was working, too, on the previous server.

Running the script with `strace` didn't reveal anything, since the last thing in it is the system call for `echo "Execute";`, which is `29936 19:44:18 write(1, "Execute\n", 8) = 8`.

The connection object is not `FALSE`, and even if it was, it should fail with another error, right?

Here comes the weirdest part:
This procedure *does not fail* when I run the script, limiting the number of pages visited and the script completes successfully. However, when I set a higher limit, it fails, *always* on the first call to this procedure, and precisely on this line.

If anyone has any suggestions what could be causing this, they would be deeply appreciated.

I can paste code if anyone needs to see a larger picture, but the procedure is very long and boring to death (may be that's why the script is failing :).

Here is how the script starts: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`.
No error is reported besides the 'magical' `Segmentation fault`. I'm not using APC.

Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm using CLI to run the script, not a web-interface.

PHP version is 5.3.8, MySQL version is 5.1.56. The memory limit is set to 64MB.

EDIT: The procedure failing + some of the other code is uploaded here: http://codepad.org/KkZTxttQ. The whole file is huge and ugly, and I believe irrelevant, so I'm not posting it for now. The line that's failing is 113.

Comment: Did you simply try to re-install the php-cli? Is there anything suspicious in the error log? (Do you even have an error log for the cli)? Do you have APC?

Comment: To your questions, in order: I'll try reinstalling php-cli, haven't tried it yet; The logging is set to max level, and yet only "Segmentation fault" appears before the crash, I'll add this to the statement of the question and no, I don't have APC. Thanks for you time :)

Comment: @K.Steff `the procedure is very long and boring to death (may be that's why the script is failing :).` - ROFL :) however it would probably be an idea to show us the code, especially as this is a such an odd sounding problem. Make sure you include the code for the limiting mechanism that can "fix" the problem by lowering it, I suspect the key is in there somewhere. If you can't reasonably post it all here, try [codepad](http://codepad.org/). And, by a long way (IMHO) the most common cause of SIGSEGV is an infinite loop or infinite function recursion.

Comment: @DaveRandom Hi, thank you, I added a link to the code of the procedure in question and a few other things from the script. The "limiting mechanism" for the problem is just limiting the number of "products" that the procedure is run on to. I doubt it is an infinite loop, or an endless recursion, since this is the first and only time this function is executed (since it outputs a lot of stuff  each time it is)

Comment: @DaveRandom Also, I forgot to mention, I haven't included all of the code, since it's not a decision that depends entirely on me, for which I am sorry :(

Comment: After having had a look at your code, first of all I would suggest to add this -- echo "stmt_error: ".mysqli_stmt_error ($prepCheck); -- just after line #111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer to my own question, since I've solved the issue, and there are no other answers...

Credit goes to @jap1968 for pointing to me to the function mysqli_stmt_error (which I assumed I would not need, since I have `error_reporting(E_ALL)`).

The problem was that MySQL had a very weird default configuration: particularly

```
connect_timeout = 10
wait_timeout = 30
```

This caused the MySQL server to close the connection after only 30 seconds (default is more than a half hour, according to MySQL website). This in turn, caused the mysqli_stmt_bind_result function to fail with a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: Have you reported the segmentation fault in the PHP bugtracker?

Comment: Honestly I didn't realize it was a bug in PHP. Now that I think, it should probably react in a different way. So no, I haven't but I will search for it, and if missing, I'll report it.

Comment: That would be really kind of you. Also one might want to find out if this still does segfault with a current version. I just ran over your question today otherwise I've commented that already earlier. Let me know if you need some help.