# How to bind_result() in PHP with SHA512 value?

Tags: php, mysqli, sha512

This is the code I am trying to execute:

```
$query = "SELECT `UserID`, `password` FROM Users WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($user_id, $db_pass);
$stmt->fetch();

echo 'ID: '.$user_id.'<br>';
echo 'Password: '.$db_pass.'<br>';
```

The password field is an sha512 hashed value. When I only query the user_id and not the password the code works great. Once I try to query the password field chrome says the server never responded. The problem seems to be particularly with the bind_result function, if I try to bind a variable to the password field it won't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you're missing a ` after password

Comment: @pala_ Thanks but that wasn't the problem the original code has that, just a typo while writing up the question.

Comment: are you able to run the script from the commandline, not via the browser?

Comment: Do you use $db_pass variable somewhere else? For example during creating a db connection? The variable is passed to bind_result by link, so there may be a problem with that. If you do, try to change variable's name.

Comment: not to mention you bind to `$db_pass` and then echo `$db_password` - another typo or is this an actual inconsistency?

Comment: @phoenix.mstu I do not you $db_pass anywhere else in my code. This is the only portion where I query the password from the database.

Comment: @pala_ That was an actually inconsistency but fixing it didn't change anything chrome still says the server isn't sending it any data.

Comment: set up and check an SQL error log

Comment: Interesting, when I run from command line it gives me a segmentation fault.

Comment: try here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547751/php-weird-seg-faults-on-mysqli-stmt-bind-result

Comment: Look at this:
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php#57564
probably it is because PHP tries to allocate too many memory.